What's the proper keyboard layout for the slim keyboard Froggit PK-703 in Gnome on Debian 12 bookworm?
What's the proper (German) keyboard layout for the slim keyboard Froggit PK-703


(Source: http://www.amazon.de/dp/B073WFDMXJ) in Gnome on Debian 12 bookworm?  As of now, the computer to which the keyboard is attached has
# cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBMODEL=pc105
XKBLAYOUT=de
BACKSPACE=guess
# localectl status
System Locale: LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: de
   X11 Layout: de
    X11 Model: pc105
# localectl list-keymaps
Failed to read list of keymaps: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

and this might hypothetically be a source of problems. Does /etc/default/keyboard have to be changed? Anything else to be changed anywhere?
